# SSAS database backup fails with the error 3239837698

Tags: backup, ssas

When I run XMLA query to backup SSAS database

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine" Transaction="false" >
  <Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Object>
      <DatabaseID>MyDB</DatabaseID>
    </Object>
    <File>D:\SSAS\OLAP\Backup\MyDB.abf</File>
    <AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite>
  </Backup>
</Batch>
```

It runs for an hour, creates backup file, and gives me an error:

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
  <results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/xmla-multipleresults">
    <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty">
      <Exception xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception" />
      <Messages xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception">
        <Error ErrorCode="3239837698" Description="Server: The operation has been cancelled." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
      </Messages>
    </root>
  </results>
</return>
```

Log says:
`Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaException: Server: The operation has been cancelled.

at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForSoapFault(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.CheckForError(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean endReceivalIfException, Boolean readSession, Boolean readNamespaceCompatibility)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.SendMessageAndReturnResult(String& result, Boolean skipResult)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.Execute(String command, String properties, String& result, Boolean skipResult, Boolean propertiesXmlIsComplete)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.ExecuteStatement(String stmt, StatementType stmtType, Boolean withResults, String properties, String parameters, Boolean restrictionListElement, String discoverType, String catalog)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.SendCommand(String command, Boolean withResults, String properties)
   at OlapEvent(SCH_STEP* pStep, SUBSYSTEM* pSubSystem, SUBSYSTEMPARAMS* pSubSystemParams, Boolean fQueryFlag)Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaException: Server: The operation has been cancelled.
`

I am not sure if backup is good.

Comment: Are there any messages/logs associated with this error?

Comment: 3239837698 => "The operation has been cancelled.".  Seems unlikely - so I'd hope there are other errors...

Comment: Where are you running the XMLA query - does it take a while (i.e. long enough for whatever you're running it through to 'timeout') before failing?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [ForceCommitTimeout](http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2007/04/24/SSAS-Processing-ForceCommitTimeout-and-quotthe-operation-has-been-cancelledquot.aspx).

Comment: answer should be more descriptive